# Interval of Convergence on a single point

Tags: calculus

I was wondering why this series  has a single point for the interval of convergence of 7?

Question:  power series from one to infinity: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n!(x-7)^n$

[image: the question at hand]

After applying the ratio test,I know that I can factor out $x-7$ from the limit and that the limit of $(n+1)$ goes infinity meaning that it would diverge.

Comment: At $x = 7$, the sum is 0 since $a_n = n!(7 - 7)^n = 0$

Comment: Hint: you can factor out $x-7$ unless...

Comment: Are you asking why is $7$ a point of convergence or why other points are not?

Comment: @copper.hat yes, usually its an interval of convergence which implies that it should be more then one value?

Comment: It is not of much use if the ROC is zero...